# Saving Liferay Form

Tags: java, forms, liferay-7

I have NullPointerExeption when i try to save a Form with grid like this:

[grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3rGE.png)

But only when i do not check all the rows. Below is the code for saving the form:

```
DDMFormValues ddmFormValues = null;
    try {
        ddmFormValues = _ddmFormValuesFactory.create(actionRequest, latestStructureVersion.getDDMForm());
    }catch(Exception e){
        addPortalExceptionErrorAndLog(actionRequest, String.format("The values in Form Instance named %s cannot be fully extract. It seems that some value needs to be filled.", formName));
        return Optional.empty();
    }
```